# Objective-C: Syntax to call method from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods

iOS newb trying to pull an array from another class and a getting error.  Fundamentally, I don't really understand the difference between methods and properties, I realize, so this might help me get a better understanding of that.

I have created a method that returns an array.  I want to use that array in the other class (like a function returning a value in other languages) so I thought I would do it as follows:

```
class1
- (id) getTags{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tags"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSError *error      = nil;
    NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   error:&error];

    NSMutableArray * tags = [[results valueForKey:@"tag"] mutableCopy];
    return tags;
}
```

In other words, I want to use what that method returns as a sort of variable which in Objective C is called properties.  The method is also in the .h file so that it is public.

In class 2 I import class 1 at top and then try to call method as follows:

```
NSArray *newarray = [class1 getTags];
```

However I get error "No known class method for selector getTags"

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this line;

```
NSArray *newarray = [class1 getTags];
```

Actually, you should use class instance, not class itself.
To use this kind of function call, you should declare getTags as class level function(+ function), not - function

So your code should be look like this;

```
class1 *class1Instance = [[class1 alloc] init];
NSArray *newarray = [class1Instance getTags];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the code `NSArray *newarray = [class1 getTags];`

You are calling class method `getTags` in `class1`; however you only have an instance method called `getTags` in `class1`.

To solve it, change the - to + in the method signature, which will change your method from an instance method to a class method. (In java terms: + is where you put a static in the method).

However, there are quite a lot of style issues in your code.
First, I don't think putting code in .h is a good practice. What you might want is

.h

```
@interface Class1
+ (NSArray *)getTags;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation Class1
+ (NSArray *)getTags { ... }
@end
```

so you declare your public interface in .h file and implementation in .m. Also, you probably want to capitalize your class name.

You shouldn't use `id` as a return type and assign that `id` from `[class1 getTags]` to `NSArray *`. There is a implicit cast there, which sometimes could lead to some good debug time.

`NSArray` CAN be used as return type of your method because `NSMutableArray` is inherited from `NSArray` - [Apple Documentation of NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html)

Comment: I originally tried NSArray but it gave error "conflicting return type" and in return line below gave error "Returning NSMutableArray*____strong from a function with incompatible result type". Switching to id got rid of the two errors.

Comment: Did you use `NSArray *` as return type rather the `NSArray`? This is common mistake when people first learn Obj-C..